# Positivity in non-unital $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For unital algebras, we say that an element $b$ is positive if there exists an element $a$ such that $b=a^*a$ if and only if $\sigma(b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}_+$. In the non-unital case, how would one define positivity? Also, how would this fit together with the notion above when passing to unitizations?

Secondly, when introducing complete positivity of maps, the framework is usually given as an operator system (i.e., closed, selfadjoint subspaces of unital algebras). Could we do without this extra assumption and meaningfully introduce this concept for arbitrary subspaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is non-unital, and $a \in A$, we define
$$\sigma_A(a):= \sigma_{\widetilde{A}}(a)$$ where $\widetilde{A}$ is the unitisation of $A$.
We then define:

> An element $x \in A$ is called positive if it is self-adjoint and if $\sigma_A(x)\subseteq [0, \infty[$.

Note the self-adjointness assumption in the above definition (which you left out in your characterisation of positive element!).

A natural question is to see what happens if $A$ is already unital. Then for $a \in A$, we have
$$\sigma_{\widetilde{A}}(a) = \{0\}\cup \sigma_A(a).$$
Thus it does not matter if you examine positivity in $A$ or in $\widetilde{A}$ (regardless if $A$ is unital), as both notions coincide.

And yes, the notion of (complete) positive map makes sense for arbitrary subspaces of (not necessarily unital) $C^*$-algebras. Indeed, let $M\subseteq A$ a subspace of a $C^*$-algebra and $B$ a $C^*$-algebra. Then we call $f: M \to B$ positive if $f(m)$ is positive in $B$ whenever $m$ is positive in $M$ (meaning that it is positive in $A$).

---

In reply to a comment:

> Assume $A$ is non-unital and $a \in A$ is positive. Then there exists a positive element $b \in A$ with $a=b^2$.

**Proof**: Functional calculus gives us a $*$-isomorphism
$$C(\sigma_{\widetilde{A}}(a)) \to C^*(1_{\widetilde{A}}, a)\subseteq \widetilde{A}: f \mapsto f(a).$$

Apply this to the function $f= \sqrt{-}$ and let $b:= f(a)$. But $f(0)=0$, so a routine argument implies that in fact $b \in C^*(a)$ (hint: show that $f$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials with constant term $0$). Since $C^*(a)\subseteq A$, you are done. $\quad \square$

Comment: Thank you for your response and correction. Does it then follow that an element $b$ in a nonunital algebra is positive iff it decomposes as $b=a^*a$ for some element $a$?

Comment: @Deracless Yes. Isn't this clear to you (given the unital case)? What troubles do you have?

Comment: It may help to remember that the holomorphic functional calculus for a general element and the continuous functional calculus for a normal element both make sense in the non-unital case: you just restrict to functions that vanish at $0$. Thus, if $b$ is positive (and hence normal with $\sigma_{\tilde{A}}(b) \subset [0,\infty)$), then applying the function $(x \mapsto \sqrt{x}) \in C(\sigma_{\tilde{A}}(b))$ to $b$ still yields an element of $A$ itself.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I was just wondering whether the element $a$ only exists in the unitization, or in fact in the non-unital algebra itself.

Comment: @Deracless I added some details to my answer.

Comment: While positivity may be defined for arbitrary subspaces of C$^*$-algebras, it is quite a useless notion if the subspace is not selfadjiont. You could have a subspace where $0$ is the only positive element, and then every linear map on the subspace is completely positive in a vacous way. It doesn't look very nice to say that $a\longmapsto -a$ is completely positive.